# How much of Marco Polo's accounts were actually the first Western record?

Tags: asia, exploration, marco-polo

While there's already an answered question here about Marco Polo and fireworks, he is often credited with being the first Western record of many other innovations. [One website](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/explorers/page/p/polo.shtml), for example, credits him with "porcelain, coal, gunpowder, printing, paper money, and silk." I have not had the opportunity to fully go through Marco Polo's accounts, but some preliminary searching has left me feeling confused. To use coal as an example, there are [accounts](https://grandemotte.wordpress.com/the-story-of-coal/) of coal being used in Europe before Marco Polo came back from his journey - although it only became widely used many centuries later, it was still present.

In short, how many of Marco Polo's accounts are actually apocryphal?

Comment: Reversinator - Your question is badly organized,  You ask about accounts that claim Marco Polo's book was the first description of various items, and then your last sentence asks how many of Marco Polo's accounts are actually apocryphal.  If Marco Polo mentioned unreal and apocryphal events and things, he is likely to have been one of the few to do do, if not the only one and thus the first.   If events and things mentioned by Marco Polo were real, they may have been mentioned by many writers, although he could still be the first for some of them.